is CICD with Azure Logic Apps under consumption model possible?
Is ci/cd possible with logic apps on the consumption model?
All presentations and tutorials online deal only with the standard model, not consumption model.
We use visual studio to develop hundreds of logic apps under the consumption model, but with MS no longer developing the logic apps plugin, we likely have to move to VS Code and come up with a new workflow.

Yes, it is possible. Example: https://devcodef1.com/news/1090127/ci-cd-for-logic-app-connections

Thanks for inputs @ D A, and I do agree that you can follow the Document which gives an example on how to use azure devops with Consumption plan of Logic apps:
yaml:
  trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Rithwik Test'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'rithcon'  
    subscriptionId: 'b83c13f' 
    resourceGroupName: 'rg' 
    location: 'East US'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/lotmp.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)lopp-param.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

lotmp.json:
  {
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"",
        "resources": [
            {
                "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
                "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
                "name": "SimpleRecurrenceLogicApp",
                "location": "[parameters('rithloc')]",
                "properties": {
                    "definition": {
                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                        "actions": {
                            "Compose": {
                                "inputs": "Hello Rithwik",
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "Compose"
                            }
                        },
                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                        "outputs": {},
                        "parameters": {},
                        "triggers": {
                            "Recurrence": {
                                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                                    "frequency": "Minute",
                                    "interval": 1
                                },
                                "recurrence": {
                                    "frequency": "Minute",
                                    "interval": 1
                                },
                                "type": "Recurrence"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "parameters": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

lopp-param.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rithloc": {
      "value": "West US 3"
    }
  }
}

After deployment it should give design like this:

